# Is there a way to get the username(email address) of a user from Gmail native app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, gmail

Just for extra clarification, here's what I tried so far:

1. I'm checking if Gmail native app is installed via the this code:

   ```
   let urlPath:String = "googlegmail://q"
   let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

   let isInstalled = UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)
   if isInstalled {
       print("Installed")
   }else{
       print("Not installed")
   }
   ```
2. Next, I'm just trying to get the username that the user is using to access email (this is where I'm stuck).

I don't want to use private apis, but only publicly available apis.

Comment: Also, I already know how to get this info from Gmail SDK in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to confirm Delegate of Google Plus i.e GIDSignInDelegate,GIDSignInUIDelegate
after this make delegate self and add Scope

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts")
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")`

//MARK:-  get Info of user from google api
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!){
    if (error == nil){
        getGoogleContacts()
    } 
}`

private func getGoogleContacts(){


guard let currentUserToken = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.accessToken else{
        userAuthenticate()
        return
    }       GNServerAPIProcessor.requestForGetGoogleContactsFromGmail(currentUserToken) { (responseValue, error) in
        if error == nil{
            if responseValue != nil{`// here is user result with email
        }
    }
}``
```

Comment: That's is not entirely correct. I'll post my answer shortly with how to do that. But essentially you can access directly into gmail without using GooglePlus, in order to get the user's email.

Answer (score 0):

The code below, is what you'll need to get the user's username. Before you do that you'll have to authorize the user with a Gmail login WebView.

```
fileprivate func fetchMessagesContent(forIdentifier identifier:String) {
    let messageQuery = GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesGet.query(withUserId: "me", identifier: identifier)
    messageQuery.identifier = identifier
    messageQuery.format = "metadata"
    messageQuery.metadataHeaders = ["to", "From"]

    service.executeQuery(messageQuery,
                         delegate: self,
                         didFinish: #selector(displayMessageContent(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
}

@objc private func displayMessageContent(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
                                         finishedWithObject labelsResponse: GTLRGmail_Message,
                                         error: NSError?) {

    if error != nil {
        // TODO: Send fail message.
        print("Error from display messages with Custom Filter is \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    //call the API users.messages.get to all ids
    let headers = labelsResponse.payload?.headers

    //Saving data in Realm
    let gmailMessage = GmailMessage()
    gmailMessage.sender = ((headers?[0] as AnyObject).value)!
    gmailMessage.recipient = (headers?.count)! > 1 ? ((headers?[1] as AnyObject).value)! : ""
    gmailMessage.username = labelsResponse.identifier!
}
```